# [hashmap][iterator] give half values

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I have been writing a simple HashMap iteration program and came across following issue:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hm2.put("One", 1);
hm2.put("Two", 2);
hm2.put("Three", 3);
hm2.put("Four", 4);
hm2.put("Five", 5);
hm2.put("Six", 6);


Set<String> keySet = hm2.keySet();
Iterator<String> itr = keySet.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
    String key = itr.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + "Values:" + hm2.get(itr.next()));
}
```

Question - `hm2.get(itr.next())` is giving only 3 values in output while if I use hm2.get(key) then it is listing all 6 values. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

It is because whenever you do this `itr.next()` , the iterator is moving one step ahead and returning the value. So you get only 3 values when you call `itr.next()` twice in one iteration and get all six values when you call it only once. So if you all six values you should use `hm2.get(key)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are advancing the iterator (by calling `next()`) twice inside the loop, and thus "skipping" half the values. You should only call `next()` once for each time you check `hasNext()`. In this case, just reuse your local `key` variable:

```
Set<String> keySet = hm2.keySet();
Iterator<String> itr = keySet.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    String key = itr.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + "Values:" + hm2.get(key));
}
```

Note, by the way, that you could just iterate over the `entrySet()`, instead of iterating over the `keySet()` and then getting the value for each key:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = hm2.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> itr = entrySet.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = itr.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + "Values:" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Or, even more elegantly, with an enhanced for-loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hm2.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + "Values:" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Or like in [Iterator over HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422428/iterator-over-hashmap-in-java/32362231#32362231)      hm2.forEach((key, val) -> {     System.out.println("Key: " + key + "Values: " + val);     });

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Map.Entry Interface to iterate Map.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hm2.put("One", 1);
    hm2.put("Two", 2);
    hm2.put("Three", 3);
    hm2.put("Four", 4);
    hm2.put("Five", 5);
    hm2.put("Six", 6);


    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: hm2.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKey() + " Values:" + e.getValue());
    }
```